# Is paladin mount advancement strictly tied to paladin class level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, multi-classing, paladin, prestige-class

The SRD has a [table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm#specialMount) on paladin mount advancement that seems to be linked to paladin level. I was wondering how this interacted with multiclassing and prestige classes.

1. Does the paladin mount advance when the paladin is multiclassing?
2. Does the paladin mount advance when taking levels in a prestige class?
3. Does the paladin mount advance when taking levels in the *Fist of Raziel* class?

---

If the answer to the questions above is no, would it be irrational to house-rule that prestige classes that work well with the paladin class could also count on the table for paladin mount advancement?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable. The house-rule part at the end is really a different question. You should remove it and wait for answers to this question. If the answer is no you can post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

> Does the paladin mount advance when the paladin is multiclassing?

No, there's no other class that keep evolving the paladin special mount. The multiclass of Ranger and Paladin have access to the feat Devoted Tracker (CAdv 107) though that while doesn't keep evolving it allows you to choose your Special Mount as an Animal Companion and get both bonuses simultaneously.

> Does the paladin mount advance when taking levels in a prestige class?

The standard answer is no, but there are exceptions. One of those is the Cavalier PrC (CW 19) that explicitly says otherwise: "**Special Mount:** A cavalier's class levels stack with any paladin levels the character might have for determining the characteristics of a paladin's mount."

> Does the paladin mount advance when taking levels in the Fist of Raziel class?

No. The Fist of Raziel specifically says it doesn't advance the special mount in the section about its *Spells per Day* as [Taormina](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/49015/taormina) quoted [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148466/is-paladin-mount-advancement-strictly-tied-to-paladin-class-level/148467#148467).

> If the answer to the questions above is no, would it be irrational to house-rule that prestige classes that work well with the paladin class could also count on the table for paladin mount advancement?

Not really if the class in question is focused in the mount aspect like the Cavalier mentioned before. Notice that PrCs usually specialize in certain abilities/acquire new abilities and discard others in order to follow its concept and keep as balanced as possible (I'm looking at you non-druid PrCs with full casting and several abilities. Shame on you!).

Then a class that "work well" with Paladin that has a focus on mounts could advance it. However, if it also advances Smite Evil, Turning Undead and spells per day it would be "working well" too much like an upgraded Paladin 2.0 instead of a path for the Paladin. So I would rule out most Paladin PrCs since they usually focus on Smite Evil or another core Paladin aspect. Although a PrC that gives at least one ability for mounted use like a the Mounted Combat feat (not as an option of bonus feat, but as fixed feature), different special mounts or another feature exclusive for mounted combat would probably be OK if they don't already do it.

Comment: I would note that given that Paladin is a fairly low-power class, for most PrCs there should be no balance issue in allowing the mount to remain useful.

Answer (score 2):

Per the rules on [Ex-Paladins](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm#exPaladins), you'll need to remember that multiclassing out of paladin into Fist of Raziel will prevent you from ever taking more paladin levels. Fist of Raziel specifically allows you to stack your paladin level and PrC levels for certain things (smites), but there's nothing about the advancing the Paladin's mount, which as you note is tied to the actual number of Paladin levels. Generally speaking, PrCs that provide additional spellcasting levels (which this doesn't actually for that 1st level) don't also provide class features for the base class.

Additionally, Fist of Raziel specifically calls out the fact that you aren't supposed to improve your mount while leveling the PrC.

> **Spells per Day**: Starting at 2nd level, and at each level thereafter, a fist of Raziel gains new spells per day as if she had also gained a
>   level in a divine spellcasting class to which she belonged before adding the prestige class level. She does not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained (improved
>   chance of turning or destroying undead, improved special mount, and so on).

So, I think:

1. No
2. No
3. No

Now, if we assume a PrC like Knight of the Chalice (Complete Warrior, p. 53) which contains:

> Multiclass Note: A paladin who becomes a knight of the Chalice may continue advancing as a paladin.

Then I think that the original answer holds, but you have the option to return to being a paladin later in your adventuring career to better your mount.